# Neo4j cypher LOAD command with wrong where condition

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two tables incidents and location.

I have downloaded them to csv files.

I Run the following queries to create nodes:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:////path/tb_location.csv" AS row
CREATE(:tb_location{ latitude: row.latitude,longitude: row.longitude,location_description: 
row.location_description,community_area: row.community_area,block: row.block,district: row.district,ward: row.ward,x_coordinate: row.x_coordinate,y_coordinate: row.y_coordinate,id_city: row.id_city,composite_key: row.composite_key });


USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:////path/tb_incident.csv" AS row
CREATE(:tb_incident{ id: row.id,primary_type: row.primary_type,domestic: row.domestic,date: row.date,description: row.description,arrest: row.arrest,beat: row.beat,year: row.year,updated_on: row.updated_on,latitude : row.latitude,longitude: row.longitude,case_number: row.case_number,composite_foreign_key: row.composite_foreign_key});
```

Then i create indexes on match attributes:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :tb_incident(composite_foreign_key);

CREATE INDEX ON :tb_location(composite_key);
```

Then i try to create relationships:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:////path/tb_incident.csv" AS row1
MATCH(tb_incident:tb_incident{composite_foreign_key: row1.composite_foreign_key})
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:////path/tb_location.csv" AS row2
MATCH(tb_location:tb_location{composite_key: row2.composite_key})
WHERE tb_incident.composite_foreign_key = tb_location.composite_key
MERGE (tb_incident)-[:occured_at]->(tb_location);
```

However last query links one incident to all the locations. 
I am new to cypher and i couldnt locate what i am doing wrong. I intend to link one incident with one location only. 
Please help if you can help me correct this improper query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already imported all the data, there is no need to use your CSV files any more. And that might be what is causing your issue.

Try this instead:

```
MATCH (tb_incident:tb_incident), (tb_location:tb_location)
WHERE tb_incident.composite_foreign_key = tb_location.composite_key
MERGE (tb_incident)-[:occured_at]->(tb_location);
```

That query's complexity is N*M (where N is the number of `tb_incident` nodes and M is the number of `tb_location` nodes), so it can  take awhile. Unfortunately, neo4j does not use indices when comparing values between nodes.

[UPDATED]

### Improving performance by creating relationship during import

When you were importing from the second CSV file, you had the opportunity to not only create each `tb_incident` node, but also create the corresponding relationship. The `MATCH` it uses *should* be able to use the index, since it does not need to compare values between nodes. This means that the complexity of this step is reduced to just N:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:////path/tb_incident.csv" AS row
CREATE(tb_incident:tb_incident{ id: row.id,primary_type: row.primary_type,domestic: row.domestic,date: row.date,description: row.description,arrest: row.arrest,beat: row.beat,year: row.year,updated_on: row.updated_on,latitude : row.latitude,longitude: row.longitude,case_number: row.case_number,composite_foreign_key: row.composite_foreign_key})
WITH tb_incident, row.composite_foreign_key AS cfk
MATCH (tb_location:tb_location{composite_key: cfk})
MERGE (tb_incident)-[:occured_at]->(tb_location);
```

Comment: This again did the same thing as my query was doing. Connected one incident to all the locations. Interestingly the last incident (incident with highest id is the one the relationships are getting attached to)

Comment: I was trying to follow [this](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-importing-data-and-etl/) guide. They also use indexes. am i missing something?

Comment: Hmm. Can you take a look at a few of the location nodes in your database (MATCH (location:tb_location) RETURN location LIMIT 5) and see if they have the same composite_key? If the result of this is connecting to multiple locations, that makes me think locations weren't created correctly, that there are many with the same composite_key.

Comment: @cybersam Would you be able to get this down to complexity N if you first matched on tb_incident, and WITH incident matched on location with the WHERE on the joined keys? With an index on the composite_key, that should eliminate the cartesian join, right?

Comment: Silly me, actually you are right.... i was trying to do it on a a 5 row table first instead of one with million rows. looks like i didnt extract the location composite key right. They are the same in all 5 rows. I'll fix this and then give a try

Comment: I just deleted the nodes and reloaded the data and everything works fine. Thanks. I will accept the answer. Not really sure on indexes though. I am using it because the guide says it helps.

Comment: Indices are only used in certain situations.

Comment: See my update to my answer. By merging during the second import, you could use the `:tb_location(composite_key)` index to reduce the complexity to N.

Comment: Thanks. This all makes sense. I am going to write a cypher query builder in python for above. Maybe I'll post some metrics on how much time this takes vs the old way.